# How to use MkDir with variable path for different users

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code where you input information in an excel list. I want to be able to create a folder - I am using the code below. The issue is that I want it to work for all my colleagues (not just me). Can someone please help find where I am getting an error? Note this is a partial code, the error is happening on the MkDir line. Thanks for your help in advance!

```
Dim Startupfolder As String
Startupfolder = Startup_Name.Value

MkDir Environ$("Userprofile") & "\nc Dropbox\investment oportunities\ & "Startupfolder"
```

Comment: The MKDir line contains a syntax error. The second issue will be that you need to make sure that the complete path before _Startupfolder_ exists. And do you really wnt to put the new path just below the _userprofile_? IMO _Documents_ would possibly be the better place.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is where you put your quotes. Try this:

```
MkDir Environ$("Userprofile") & "\nc Dropbox\investment oportunities\" & Startupfolder
```

Startupfolder is variable, so you don't want that within quotes

**More info**
If your folder is put in a not yet existing folder, it will fail. It will also fail if it already exists.

Try this instead:

```
Sub MakeDir()
    CreateFolder Environ$("Userprofile") & "\nc Dropbox"
    CreateFolder Environ$("Userprofile") & "\nc Dropbox\investment oportunities"
    CreateFolder Environ$("Userprofile") & "\nc Dropbox\investment oportunities\" & Startupfolder
End Sub

Sub CreateFolder(Folder)
    If Len(Dir(Folder, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
        MkDir Folder
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: unfortunately it still does not work it the line with MKdir is highlighted in yellow

Comment: @rajpabs you missed an important point mentioned by Storax below your question. ;)

Comment: @SiddharthRout C:\Users\XXXX\nc Dropbox\investment oportunities does exist - XXXX being my full name

Comment: @rajpabs - added a bit more info now

Comment: @rajpabs: Then the code by Sam will work. What is the error that you are getting. Also those folders may not be present for other users so you need an extra code to check if they exists or not and create it..

Comment: sorry to trouble you - getting a yellow highlight in this line now: If Len(Dir(Folder, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then

Answer (score 2):

I would use an API Call like that

```
Declare Function MakeSureDirectoryPathExists Lib "imagehlp.dll" ( _
  ByVal lpPath As String) As Long
```

and then you could call it like that

```
    MakeSureDirectoryPathExists Environ$("Userprofile") & _
         "\nc Dropbox\investment oportunities\" & Startupfolder & "\"
```

For a documentation look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/dbghelp/nf-dbghelp-makesuredirectorypathexists) resp [here](http://allapi.mentalis.org/apilist/MakeSureDirectoryPathExists.shtml). Important as pointed out in the comments

> If the final component of the path is a directory, not a file name, the string must end with a backslash character.

Comment: [This](http://allapi.mentalis.org/apilist/MakeSureDirectoryPathExists.shtml) is a better link. It is my fav one stop place for API information ;)

Comment: Thanks, I usually go [here](https://www.vbarchiv.net/api/api_makesuredirectorypathexists.html) but this is obviously not the right one for SO so I put the link to the MS documentation.

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Function MakeFolder(FolderPath As String)

' if 123 is a folder then the path shall have a backslash at the end"
' e.g. strFolderName = "d:\abcd\efh\123\\"

Dim OFL As Integer
Dim OFR As Integer
Dim trimmedFolderPath As String

         OFL = InStr(1, FolderPath, "\")
         OFR = Len(FolderPath) - InStr(1, StrReverse(FolderPath), "\") + 1
        
        
         trimmedFolderPath = Left([FolderPath], OFL)
         
        Do While OFL <= OFR
         
           
                If Dir(trimmedFolderPath, vbDirectory) = "" Then
                    
                        MkDir trimmedFolderPath
                    
                Else
                        OFL = InStr(OFL + 1, FolderPath, "\")
                        
                        If OFL > 0 Then
                             
                             trimmedFolderPath = Left([FolderPath], OFL - 1)
                            
                        Else
                             Exit Function
                        End If
                End If
        Loop
End Function
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.