# Create a Folder if that folder already Exists create a sub-folder VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Looking for a bit of guidance with using VBA to carry out this process. Very new to VBA so a bit unsure how to do this, have tried some examples but haven't seemed to work.

Background,

So i carry out weekly reports, and have the month and WC commencing values on my homepage, in Cell I5 and I7 respectively. I will move my PDF exports into these folders.

with VBA I'd like to create the Main Folder in, say for example Directory X. Then Create the sub-folder, as the value of I7, WC 08-06 for example in the screen grab.  Then when i carry out the weekly analysis the week later if the Jun main folder already exists then create the sub-folder within that, again based on the value of I7.

Eventually the value of I5, jun in this case, will then be Jul, and so on.

Is there a way to use VBA that would create the Main folder based on the value of I5 then create the Sub folder based on the value of I7. It would have to have the caveat of, if the main folder exists, just move onto creating the sub folder. But if it doesn't create the main folder then go on to create the sub-folder.

[Screen shot of my excel document showing the values of I5 and I7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYPJa.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43658276/create-folder-path-if-does-not-exist-saving-issue

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55100589/6600940